# IntelliJ & MAC and Java 1.8 -- How when 1.6 seems to be default. Can't change?

Tags: java, intellij-plugin

I am a MAC newbie - just recently was handed a mac at a new job. Anyways, I have IntelliJ installed and the default Java 1.6. Ok -- but I want to use Java 1.8 for all my projects. So, when I open IntelliJ and try to add a new SDK -- I can't or lets say _ "I have NO idea how".

My MAC: 10.9.5

When I run java -version, I get: 1.6
which Java: usr/bin/java

When I open 'spotlight' -> System Preferences -> Java -> Java Tab -> view -> 
**I get:**
platform: 1.8 , 
product: 1.8.0_25, 
path: /Library/Internet Plug-Ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin/Contents/Home/bin/java

When I look under my "versions": System/Library/Versions... I only see: 1.5, 1.6

So, to be honest - I am very confused :-)

Any help on getting this 1.8 to be "seen"

Comment: What version OSX are you running?  You may need to install Java 8 on the machine if it isn't already.  And Java 8 is not officially supported on Lion (10.7.x).

Comment: I have 10.9.5 , I will update the OP

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to install the full [Java SE Development Kit](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html).

What you have at the moment is merely the Java plugin.